# Debugging Selenium JS application on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, selenium, debugging

Im NodeJS newbie. I have JS  application for running selenium-based tests of web aplication. My problem is that I cannot debug this application.

How to debug my JS application. My editor is Visual Studio :) or any simple text editor.

My application is started by code 
`node src/test/UI/app/Tests.js`

Any module needed for debuging JS apps started under NodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, you can debug your Node.js in [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/).

There are two scenarios of how you can do that.

- [Remote debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html). In that case you need to run you test with --inspect flag (`node --inspect <pathToTest>`). Then you need to create a debug configuration (port 9229 is a default debugging port used by Node.js). See details on the screenshot bellow.
  [image: Node.js remote debugging]
- [Start Node.js app through WebStorm debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-node-js.html). In that case you just have to specify another debug configuration by setting path to node binary and specifying application entry point (in that case it is your test file). Screenshot bellow illustrates details.
  [image: Debugging Node.js app using WebStorm]

After that set a break point and launch your selenium test.
Happy debugging.